# Frictionless surface moment of inertia newtons first law and shpere

Tags: moment-of-inertia

If we accept the surface frictionless and inclined, can a sphere rotate on it?

Answer (score 0):

If we *imagine* a frictionless surface, then of course a sphere can rotate however it likes while touching it, without any loss of energy.

If we were to release a *stationary* sphere on a frictionless inclined surface, then it would not *roll*. It would glide downhill without spinning at all. We can intuit this from a kinematics diagram by noting that all the force vectors pass through the center of the sphere.

We could get an ok approximation of this in the real world. We would want a dense ball and an extreamly steep surface with low mutual friction. A bowling ball on a polished 85° ramp should work; set up a slow-motion camera to observe that the ball scrapes downward against the ramp, which pushes it sideways, probably for a couple meters before it really starts rotating.